# Read in parallel multiples files in Python

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, parsing

I have the following code, which reads several files and puts some information or each row to a `MySQL` database. However, this process is slow.

```
def extractAF(files_vcf):
...
for infile_name in sorted(files_vcf):
    print infile_name
    ###single files
    vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(infile_name, 'r'))
    for record in vcf_reader:
        snp_position='_'.join([record.CHROM, str(record.POS)])
        ref_F = float(record.INFO['DP4'][0])
        ref_R = float(record.INFO['DP4'][1])
        alt_F = float(record.INFO['DP4'][2])
        alt_R = float(record.INFO['DP4'][3])
        AF = (alt_F+alt_R)/(alt_F+alt_R+ref_F+ref_R)
        if not snp_position in snp_dict:
            sql_insert_table = "INSERT INTO snps VALUES ('" + snp_position + "'," + ",".join(list(('0') for _ in range(len(files_vcf)))) + ")"
            cursor = db1.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql_insert_table)
            db1.commit()
            snp_dict.append(snp_position)
        sql_update = "UPDATE snps SET " + str(z) + "g=" + str(AF) + " WHERE snp_pos='" + snp_position + "'";
        cursor = db1.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_update)
        db1.commit()
    z+=1
return snp_dict
```

How could I read several files at the same time in order to speed up my program?

Comment: Have you tried the `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: The slowdown might be due to database commits after every row. If you can commit only once in 1000 rows, that can improve the speeds.

Comment: How would I do that, @styts

Comment: Have a counter, increment it on each row, only call `db1.commit()` if `counter % 1000 == 0`

Comment: If your table is empty before executing your script, you may also use MySQL's `load data infile` command, which is by far faster than inserting/updating many times.

Comment: Or if you dont want to modify your script, you can have `xargs -P .. -n ..` launch multiple processes for you. In that case, just pass one file to your function extractAf(..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing a database call, so I can assume, that that your application is I/O bound. In your scenario you can use `threading` module. Make each thread do it's IO calls, something like this:

Prep files:

```
root@123-PC:/tmp/test$ for i in {a,b,c,d,e}; do echo foo_$i > $i;done
root@123-PC:/tmp/test$ ls
a  b  c  d  e
```

Run the code in parallel:

```
import threading
import time
import random

def worker(f_n):
    with open(f_n) as f:
        time.sleep(random.random())
        print f_n, " => ", f.read()

f_list = ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

threads = []
for f_n in f_list:
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(f_n))
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.start()


for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Output 1-st time:

```
a  =>  foo_a

e  =>  foo_e

b  =>  foo_b

c  =>  foo_c

d  =>  foo_d
```

Output 2-nd time:

```
d  =>  foo_d

e  =>  foo_e

a  =>  foo_a

b  =>  foo_b

c  =>  foo_c
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can take a look of which lines are the slow ones, there is a nice [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) for python that you can check.
Then, maybe you can think of splitting the function in two, one for reading files in parallel and another to bulk all the information into the DB.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, assuming each file is not a very large file.Just put

```
db1.commit()
```

outside the `for loop`. That means it have to execute when `for loop` finishes.

Then if you want to read file `parallely`, you can use `Threads` , `Multiprocessing`.